# How exactly works this Hibernate entity class mapping that implement a recursive relationship on the same DB table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring Boot portal using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate mapping and I am finding some difficulties trying to understand how exactly works the following code implemented by someone else (it works fine but JPA\Hibernate are not my cup of tea and I am missing something).

On the database I have this **portal_user** table representing the users of my application

[image]

As you can see this table contains the **parent_id** field that is a FK of the **portal_user** table itself. This is used to create a recursive relation between an user and its parent (you can see it is a classical refferal relationship: the parent is the user who bring another user into the system).

This **portal_user** DB table was mapped on this **User** entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5062673109048808267L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.firstName.Validation}")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name = "surname")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.surname.Validation}")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name = "sex")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.sex.Validation}")
    private char sex;
    
    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.birthdate.Validation}")
    private Date birthdate;
    
    @Column(name = "tax_code")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.taxCode.Validation}")
    private String taxCode;
    
    @Column(name = "e_mail")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.email.Validation}")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "pswd")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.pswd.Validation}")
    private String pswd;
    
    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.contactNumber.Validation}")
    private String contactNumber;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean is_active;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "portal_user_user_type", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
    )
    Set<UserType> userTypes;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonProperty("subagent")
    private User parent;

    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public User(String firstName, String middleName, String surname, char sex, Date birthdate, String taxCode,
            String email, String pswd, String contactNumber, Date createdAt, boolean is_active) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
        this.email = email;
        this.pswd = pswd;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }
    

}
```

In particular this relationship seems to be handled by this field:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonProperty("subagent")
private User parent;
```

Then I have this service method used to insert a new object into the **portal_user** table taking into account the fact that the **parent_id** field could be set:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User insertClientUser(User clientUser) throws DuplicateException, SubAgentUserNotExist, NotFoundException {
    String subAgentEmail = null;
    if(clientUser.getParent() != null) subAgentEmail = clientUser.getParent().getEmail();

    User checkClientUserExist = this.getUserByemail(clientUser.getEmail());

    if (checkClientUserExist != null) {
        String MsgErr = String.format("User %s already registered in the system !!! "
                + "Impossible to use POST", clientUser.getEmail());

        log.warning(MsgErr);

        throw new DuplicateException(MsgErr);
    }

    log.info(String.format("UserServiceImpl --> insertClientUser client user: %s %s - subagent email: %s ", 
             clientUser.getFirstName(), clientUser.getSurname(), subAgentEmail));

    // check if present because we could add a user without assigned subagent
    if(subAgentEmail != null) {

        User subAgentUser = this.getUserByemail(subAgentEmail);

        if (subAgentUser == null) {
            String errorMessage = String.format("Subagent user %s doesn't exist in the sistem !!! "
                    + "Impossible to use POST", subAgentEmail);

            log.warning(errorMessage);

            throw new SubAgentUserNotExist(errorMessage);
        }

        clientUser.setParent(subAgentUser);
    }
    
    User insertedClientUser = userRepository.save(clientUser);
    
    return insertedClientUser;
}
```

**NOTE:** the **client** is the user that I am inserting as a new record of the **portal_user** DB table while the **subAgentUser** is an user that yet exist into this DB table and that will be the parent of the user that I am inserting.
So basically, on my **portal_user** table I will have a new record (the client user) having the **parent_id** that will contain the ID of the subagent user.

How this method works is pretty simple:

1. Check if the current user that I have to insert doesn't exist into the **portal_user** table. If the user doesn't yet exist into the table it means that it have to be inserted.
2. It retrieve the subagent user (the **parent**) calling another service method and set it as **parent** property of the client user that we are inserting.
3. Finnally it save this client user into the **portal_user** DB table.

Ok it all pefrectly works but I can not understand how Hibernate is correctly setting the value of the **parent_id** field of this new inserted method. This **parent_id** field contains the PK of the parent object (the retrieved **subAgentUser** object.

If I explore my **portal_user** table after the execution of the previous service method I found what I expect:

[image]

The last row is the inserted object. As you can see the value of the **parent_id** FK field is 53 that is the PK of the expected parent user in the same table.

It works fine but I cannot understand how. Who said to Hibernate how to set the value of this FK? In particular I am confuserd because it seems that there is not a explicit mapping to this field into my **User** entity class, infact I have:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonProperty("subagent")
private User parent;
```

So what am I missing? How it exactly work?

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate, @ManyToOne specifies a single-valued association to another entity class that has many-to-one multiplicity. In this context, it is associated with the same entity.

ORM maps the data from an object model to a relational model and vice versa. So the relationships are mapped using the entities. This helps us to traverse from parent to child objects easily. We can build multiple nested relationships and can be queried or create the objects by traversing using dot and chaining method.

As we know that each entity has its own lifecycle and once the association is set, **Hibernate maps the foreign key with the primary identifier of the associated entity**.
Here it assigns to the id column which is a primary key. However, it can be customized using @JoinColumn annotation.

Below is the sql that is generated by Hibernate after creating  portal_user table to set the association.

```
alter table portal_user 
       add constraint FKdgqt4pnsjho6u58mtnackj4h8 
       foreign key (parent_id) 
       references portal_user
```

When subAgentUser entity is set to clientUser  as below, **hibernate maps the record to the primary identifier of the associated entity(subAgentUser) using parent_id column while flushing the query.**

```
 clientUser.setParent(subAgentUser);
```